# Debugging a failed transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging

I have a smart contract deployed to mainnet. A user has executed a transaction that resulted in a revert failure. How can I debug this transaction to determine what exactly happened that resulted in this failure?

(I have the smart contract source code)

Comment: You can review the transaction hash on etherscan.io. You can also post it here, so perhaps someone can help you with it. You might also want to post you contract source code here, and indicate which function was called on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For debugging transaction you can use traceTransaction debugging method that will attempt to run transaction as it was executed in the network. You can get more details from this official documentation: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction

Answer (score 4):

I found this tool and it was quite helpful to me:

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc/0x04ef5c9c98b8691adda9dff6d9363658c61a3b6004a61292f05001bfab6300e9